# How to swap elements in a struct

Tags: c

Okay let's say for example that there is this struct:

```
struct student
{
    int mark;
    char name[30], surname[30];
}s[101];
```

And I want to order the lines of variables if the names are in alphabetical order, but if the names are the same, we go to the surname and do the same thing.

This is what I tried doing:

```
int i, j;
student aux;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < 101; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(aux, s[i]);
                strcpy(s[i], s[j]);
                strcpy(s[j], aux);
            }
            else if(strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name) == 0 && strcmp(s[i].surname, s[j].surname) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(aux, s[i]);
                strcpy(s[i], s[j]);
                strcpy(s[j], aux);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I get this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘student’ to ‘char*’
```

And I don't really know what to do.

Comment: `strcpy(aux, s[i]);` you need to provide the struct's array member name instead.

Comment: Don't tag languages other than the one used. I'm guessing you're using [tag:c] so I removed [tag:c++]. Feel free to fix if I got it backwards.

Comment: Also note that we can swap structs like this: `mystruct tmp = struct1; struct1 = struct2; struct2 = tmp;`. Not always correct or the most efficient, but it this specific case, probably quite good. This is the only time C allows us to copy arrays by assignment: when they sit inside a surrounding struct.

Comment: You can assign whole structures: `aux = s[i]; s[i] = s[j]; s[j] = aux;`. In C it must be `struct student aux;` unless you use `typedef struct { ... } student`.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy(aux, s[i]);`

Here you use `aux` which is a `struct student` in `strcpy` function which takes a `char *` as its argument. The error explains it.

You probably want to use `aux.name` or `aux.surname` there instead.

Comment: Or even better `student aux;` -> `char aux[30];` and leave the `strcpy(aux, ...;` alone

Comment: ...But actually I think the 3rd comment to the question is the _actual_ answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).